# Install order for SQL Server 2005 developer and VS 2008 on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I always seem to battle with this so on my new Windows 7 dev PC build, I thought I'd try and get it right!

Do you install VS 2008 first and then SQL Server 2005 developer or the other way around? And for either way, are there any special options/settings that have to be enabled/disabled?

I've just take an Acronis image of my PC, configured IIS for use with SQL Server 2005 (see below) and proceed to install SQL Server 2005 developer. It's warned about SQL Server 2005 needing SP3 (no problem) but it's also warned about VS 2005 not been compatible. Can I ignore this and go ahead and install VS 2008?

Cheers, Rob.

PS. The page to configure IIS features for use with SQL Server 2005 is http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/920201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always install in the following order

1. IIS
2. Windows Installer
3. Sql Server
4. VS any version

whenever i tried to go the other way, i always faced a problem approx thrice i faced this problem. Usually some components becomes missing in other way

Comment: Yes, this order worked except I unchecked the installation of SQL Express when installing VS. In the past, I've had problems with the service packs when both SQL Express & Developer 2005 were both installed. But then again, that was on Vista and had lots of problems there :-)